# android firebase database how to retrieve all data from child node

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got an app where it retrieves a bunch of data from firebase but I cant seem to make it work.

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference().child("Sold").child("Item");

myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArrayList);


    myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            myArrayList.add(value);
            myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

It doesnt give me any error but it just closes my app.
Im trying to access URL/Sold/Item and pass the data in my listview

[image: Click this to see my firebase thank you]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a reference with this:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference().child("Sold").child("Item");
```

And then you add a `ChildEventListener`. That means that the `DataSnapshot` in your `onChildAdded` will be called with a snapshot of the `DUMMY 1` node first, and then with a snapshot of the `DUMMY 2` node.

You're calling `dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)` in `onChildAdded`. But since `DUMMY 1` and `DUMMY 2` have multiple properties, they don't have a single string value. So that call returns `null`, which is probably what's causing you problems.

If you want to add the `DUMMY 1`, `DUMMY 2` key itself to the adapter, you can call `dataSnapshot.getKey()`. Otherwise you can get the value of the specific child properties with `dataSnapshot.child("Description").getValue(String.class)`.

So:

```
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        String description = dataSnapshot.child("Description").getValue(String.class);
        Long quantity = dataSnapshot.child("Quantity").getValue(Long.class);
        myArrayList.add(key+": "+description+" ("+quantity+")");
        myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

---

If you'd like to read the entire value into a class representing the item (a so-called POJO), the simplest class is:

```
public class Item {
  public String Description;
  public Long Quantity;
}
```

Note that the name (including the case) of the fields must exactly match the names of the properties in your database. You can use the above class like this:

```
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        Item item = dataSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);
        myArrayList.add(key+": "+item.description+" ("+item.quantity+")");
        myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir! What if I make an object that takes Description and Quantity, How will I do that sir?

Comment: I added an example of that. Searching for `firebase` `android` `pojo` should give more questions to glean info from.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! Im still new to firebase and android. This helps a lot! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot convert the dataSnapshot you are receiving into a String.

So it would be bettor to do like this:

```
 myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dummys : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String description = dummys.child("Description").getValue(String.class);
                        int Quantity = dummys.child("Quantity").getValue(Integer.class);
                        //Use your variables here
                    }                        
                }
```

Or if you want to create a object of Dummy:

```
public class Dummy {

String Description;
Integer Quantity;

public Dummy(String description, Integer quantity) {
    Description = description;
    Quantity = quantity;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
    return Quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    Quantity = quantity;
}
```

}

```
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    List<Dummy> dummyList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot dummys : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        dummyList.add(dummys.getValue(Dummy.class));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! I just commented on sir Frank and ask for this and just refresh the page and viola! Answered! Thank you good Sir!