# Populating listview data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I have an Android app which retrieves data from firebase.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listViewProducts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference();
    ref.child("Sold").child("Item").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
                Product value = child.getValue(Product.class);
                products.add(value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<Product> productAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
    listViewProducts.setAdapter(productAdapter);
}
```

The Product class has a String of Description and Quantity just like in the firebase.

```
   class Product {
       String Description;
       String Quantity;
   }
```

My app doesn't give me any errors but it just closes when loading my data from firebase.

Why is my app crashing? It doesn't give me any errors please help, Sirs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npbVL.png)

Edit: For logCat

```
09-28 02:24:31.404 4679-4688/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
09-28 02:24:31.414 4679-4688/? E/ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [4, 0]
09-28 02:24:31.444 2929-29436/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.vivo.smartmultiwindow
09-28 02:24:31.474 2929-29450/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.vivo.smartmultiwindow
09-28 02:24:31.474 2929-29451/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.vivo.smartmultiwindow
09-28 02:24:32.394 2929-29461/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.vivo.smartmultiwindow
09-28 02:24:32.614 7415-11587/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
09-28 02:24:34.234 29437-29437/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mark.mobilethesis, PID: 29437
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: description
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zzae(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.mark.mobilethesis.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:59)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5619)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-28 02:24:34.304 2929-3298/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '4f6cc30 com.example.mark.mobilethesis/com.example.mark.mobilethesis.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
09-28 02:24:34.324 2929-29470/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.vivo.smartmultiwindow
09-28 02:24:34.324 2929-29471/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.vivo.smartmultiwindow
09-28 02:24:34.344 2929-29472/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.vivo.smartmultiwindow
```

Comment: If the app closes, it crashed. Did you check the logcat for a stack trace?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried chaning the code 1 by 1 and its only crashing when Im putting this line "Product value = child.getValue(Product.class);"

Comment: Again, that means that there should be a stack trace in your logcat. Without that it'll be hard to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited my post Sir. I added the logcat error

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In stack trace it says "Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: description

Comment: You need to mark the fields as `public` as I've shown in my answer to your previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52541511

Comment: The error says "Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: description at MainActivity.java:59" None of the code you shared has a `sensitivity` property, so it seems unlikely that the cause is in the code you've added. Please check [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it makes it more likely that we can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i tried chaning the capitals of Description to description and Quantity to quantity and now it works thank you so much Sir. Im sorry to bother but still thank you for helping. I got a new info that stack trace thing is really helpful :)

Comment: Ah yeah, I see now. Again: use the class I had in my previous answer. The casing there matches your JSON exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems here -

Here is your model class

```
class Product {
    String Description;
    String Quantity;
}
```

But the datatype of Quantity seems to be integer in your database structure.

So, try changing your model class as-

```
class Product {
    String Description;
    int Quantity;
}
```

Comment: Its okay now Sir thank you for the help! I just tried chaning the capital letters of the variables but im confuse in my firebase It is Description now in my class it is description.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you're missing a call to `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in your `onDataChange()` method:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Iterable<DataSnapshot> children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

    for (DataSnapshot child : children) {
        Product value = child.getValue(Product.class);
        products.add(value);
    }

    productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This of course requires that you store `productAdapter` somewhere where the `onDataChange` method can access it.

Comment: I have added productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and make my adapter accessible but still it crashes. How do I check logcat Sir? It doesnt stop from scrolling down